# Cannot read property username of undefined sequelize node js express

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make user registration for my nodeJS app but it can not recognize username in my model.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
//Add user
app.post('/addUser',async (req,res)=>{
    const usernameExist = await Users.findOne({username:req.body.username})
    if (usernameExist) return res.status(404).send('Username is taken')
    //Hash password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt)
    //- - - - - - - - -
    const addUser = new Users({
        username:req.body.username,
        password:hashPassword
    })
    try {
        const savedUser = await addUser.save()
        res.send(savedUser)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).send(err)
    }
})
```

It's giving me "Cannot read property username of undefined" - error

Here is my model

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../config/database')

const Users = db.define('Users',{
    username: {
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    password: {
        type:Sequelize.STRING,

    },

})

module.exports = Users
```

any suggestions please ?

Comment: I think `req.body.username` is undefined. Can you post your request (with headers and body)?

Comment: I solved this already,The problem was bodyparser was not working